# React HooK: Cargando Datos en useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buen día,

Mi código en términos generales busca obtener a partir de un fake api completar la información de los items que se encuentran en tres carruseles (componentes definidos de manera funcional), para ello hago uso de hooks useEffect y useState para el cargue de la data previa a la visualización del componente.

Tengo el siguiente código en react

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import '../assets/styles/App.scss'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Search from '../components/Search'
import Categories from '../components/Categories'
import Carousel from '../components/Carousel'
import CarouselItem from '../components/CarouselItem'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'

const App = () => {

    const [videos, setVideos] = useState({mylist:[],originals:[],trends:[]})

    useEffect(  ()=> {

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/initalState')
            .then( response => response.json())
            .then( data =>{
                 setVideos(data)

            })

    },[])

    console.log(videos)

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header/>
            <Search/>
            { videos.mylist & videos.mylist.length > 0 &&
                    <Categories title="My List">
                        <Carousel>
                            {videos.mylist.map((video) => {

                                <CarouselItem key={video.id} {...video}/>
                            })}
                        </Carousel>
                    </Categories>

            }

                <Categories title="Platzivideo Originals">
                    <Carousel>
                        {videos.originals.map((video) => {

                            <CarouselItem key={video.id} {...video}/>
                        })}
                    </Carousel>
                </Categories>

                <Categories title="Trends">
                    <Carousel>
                        {videos.trends.map((video) => {

                            <CarouselItem key={video.id} {...video}/>
                        })}
                    </Carousel>
                </Categories>

            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

El inconveniente que tengo es que al hacer el render del componente este no carga la información de la fake api que estoy usando, por lo que no me despliega las imagenes en los dos carruseles que tengo, es decir, el estado (videos) no se actualiza a tiempo.

Me he matado la cabeza, y aún no comprendo bien el por que la api no se carga en el mount del componente.

Comment: Hola Juan, una pregunta, ¿Estas seguro si estás obteniendo datos de la API?, es que sospecho por la dirección de la API, pues apunta a http://localhost:3000, y normalmente el servidor de react se monta en ese puerto.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes:
videos.mylist & videos.mylist.length
Debes agregar otro '&':
videos.mylist **&&** videos.mylist.length

Answer (score 0):

El Problema lo tienes en el fetch debes colocar la dirección de la fake api no localhost recuerda que fetch hace una peticion , pero si lo pides al local host no te retornara nada.